# Different version of Numpy imported in Colab even after installing another version

Tags: numpy, google-colaboratory

I have a requirements.txt file something like this -

```
numpy == 1.19.5
h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0
scikit-image
```

I run the following command (in Colab) -

```
!pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It gives the following output -

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy==1.19.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-image in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (0.18.3)
```

But when I print the Numpy version, it shows it as 1.21.5. I even tried doing a separate pip install for Numpy alone, but it still imports version 1.21.5. -
[image]

Could anyone kindly help to install and import version 1.19.5 of Numpy?